# seekbar.progress needs expected type boolean

Tags: kotlin

Im new to kotlin and i am trying to follow this tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOfCEhWq8sg have a problem where the line

```
val rand = Random().nextInt(seekBar.progress)
```

gives a error

> Expected a value of type boolean

Full code:

```
 package pro.bwac.randomizer

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.SeekBar
import android.widget.TextView
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val rollButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.RollButton)
        val seekBar = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.seekBar)
        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.preNumberView)
        val ResultsTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ResultsTextView)

        rollButton.setOnContextClickListener{
            val rand = Random().nextInt(seekBar.progress)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lambda needs to return a boolean value.  
Change to:

```
rollButton.setOnContextClickListener{
    val rand = Random().nextInt(seekBar.progress)
    true
}
```